# Аналог команды iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING

Tags: android, iptables

Возникла необходимость раздавать себе интернет на ноутбук, на старом смартфоне с пятым андроидом это работало, но на новом с 10-ым на команду

> iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 64

Система мне отвечает

> iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.

Есть ли какой-то другой вариант?

Answer (score 0):

Спустя множество кусков чужого кода и мануалов по `iptables` было найдено до тупого простое решение:

```
settings put global tether_dun_required 0
echo 64 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
for interface in /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/*; do echo 64 > ${interface}/hop_limit; done
```

Завернул в модуль для Magisk: https://github.com/Asidert/Tetherilla